# Can not run react-native on android

Tags: android, react-native

How to fix this error on running react-native on android

```
Failed to construct transformer:  DuplicateError: Duplicated files or mocks. Please check the console for more info
at setModule (/home/user/HelloWorld/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:620:17)
at workerReply (/home/user/HelloWorld/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:691:9)
at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
at async Promise.all (index 16960) {
   mockPath1: 'node_modules/react-native/template/package.json',
   mockPath2: 'package.json'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could happen when there are some changes that got cached in build. remove android build folder by running

```
rm -rf android/build
```

then after closing Metro bundler terminal. run the app again by `react-native run-android`.

If the same is happening for ios remove `ios/build` and `ios/Pods` and re install Pod.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if you have multiple checkouts of your react-native project. Maybe one inside another.
This could result in detecting multiple package.json files.
Delete the duplicate checkout. Clean and Build.